# Cant for the life of me figure out what these are on my new house

Tags: exterior, renovation

We recently bought a house that was built in th 90s. We have been slowly renovating it, but we have these little things all over the exterior walls of the house. Its about 1 inch by 1 inch. It looks to have a light inside. It has a clear cover on it as well.

[image]

Comment: Light inside? Or just a reflector? Is there a pattern?

Comment: May be someone's idea of aesthetic lighting. Are they powered through wires? If so what is the voltage? AC or DC?

Comment: Fashions move too fast to find an exact match, but it sure looks a lot like a trailer (thus probably 12V DC) marker light in amber.

Comment: Look for a 12V lighting power supply (might be DC, might be AC.) Ask the neighbors if the house was exterior-lighted by those.

Comment: Its outside, I do believe its some kind of lighting, just not sure why. It is powerd through wires. Havent followed the wire yet though. None of them are on. Theres 10 all around the walls. The light on the inside is a tiny light, couldn't be anything but a little dot. Could also be a sensor for something not sure what it would be for though. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but, it's in the southeast us. Also it's a pretty nice house on a golf course, if theres any special building features of those kinds of houses, the light on the inside of it is yellow. Ive never seen anything like and ive done construction work for about 20 years

Comment: Have you unscrewed one from the wall to take a look at the back side? There may well be make/model info stamped on the back side and with this nifty thing called "the internet" a quick search should tell you exactly what it is.

Comment: This is a good question.  I cannot find this thing on google.  It looks too crappy with the exposed screws to be on a high end house.  I think it  what is leftis part of a larger thing.  I think this is an accent light which always have sconces, and someone has removed the sconces.  You can see the lighter area on the wall where the round sconce once protected the wall from dirt.